# React, update chexkbox properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

Hi my problem is that i have parrent component which has a checkbox. This parrent component has many child components with chechboxes too. I need to do this:
If i click parrent checkbox i also need set state child checkbox. But i shoul be able t o unclick some child chcekboxes after that,

My child ocmponent liik like this:

```
export class ThemePartKnowledge extends Component {

    static get propTypes() {
        return {
            knowledge: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
        };
    }

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isChecked:false,
        }
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <Card className={'themePartKnowledge ml-2'}>
                <Card.Header className={'d-flex flex-column flex-md-row p-x0'}>
                        <Form.Group controlId="formBasicCheckbox" className={'m-0 d-inline-block'}>
                            <Form.Check c type="checkbox" className={'my-auto'}/>
                        </Form.Group>
                  </Card.Header>
            </Card>
        );
    }
}
```

My parrent controller is just sending isParrentChcecked props to this component.

How could I do this what i want? Thx for help

Edit:
So my structure look like this

- Parrent

  - Child
  - Child
  - Child

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[componentDidUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) does exactly that. Here whenever `isParentChecked` is changing, I am synchronising my `isChecked` state to parent.

```js
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState){
  if(prevProps.isParentChecked !== this.props.isParentChecked){
    this.setState({isChecked: this.props.isParentChecked})
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes this works like i want but i am unable to uncheck any child now if parrent is checked,

Comment: i added checked props to Form.Check with value this.state.isChecked

Comment: I am getting this error: Failed prop type: ```You provided a `checked` prop to a form field without an `onChange` handler. This will render a read-only field. If the field should be mutable use `defaultChecked`. Otherwise, set either `onChange` or `readOnly`.```

Comment: I know i probably have to implement onChange method but i am really not sure what to write inside it

Comment: You are not setting your state after checking checkbox I believe. 
```
<Form.Check c type="checkbox" className={'my-auto'} onChange={e=>this.setState({isChecked: !this.state.isChecked})}/>
```

This might work for you. Your Form.Check component must be taking onChange prop for this to work.

Comment: Welcome @YoungL. Happy to help.